# How to create a graph with nodes as custom images?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-arrows, graphs

I want to create a graph where I will be able to write some stuff on top of the nodes, and additionally make some of the anchors bold. And I want the nodes to be custom images that I will provide, and not regular circles.

I had this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10em]
      \node[anchor=south] {\pgftext{\includegraphics{root}}}
        child {node[anchor=north] {\pgftext{\includegraphics{left_child}}}}
            child {node[anchor=north] {\pgftext{\includegraphics{final}}}}
        child {node[anchor=north] {\pgftext{\includegraphics{right_child}}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But what this code does is that the root node is displayed somewhere completely else in the document, the `left_child` and `right_child` are displayed correctly but the arrow that comes from root goes until the middle of the image, and lastly `final` node is not displayed as child of `left_child` but is displayed as child of root node. Any idea how build graphs with nodes as custom images and have the functionality such as to be able to write on top of some nodes or make some arrows bold?

Comment: Please, can you illustrate, what you like to obtain? From your code (slightly corrected, you have mismatch of curly braces) i got nice looking tree diagram as you described. Top of child nodes you have edges, which will cover text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, if I understand you correctly:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        every node/.style = {inner sep=0pt},
every label/.append style = {label distance=3pt, align = center},
           level distance = 5em,
         sibling distance = 10em,
           level 1/.style = {anchor=north},
                        ]
\node[anchor=south,
      label=some text\\ above node\\ (in three lines)] {\includegraphics[width=22mm]{example-image-a}}
    child {node[label=some text] {\includegraphics[width=22mm]{example-image-b}}
        child {node[label=final\\ image] {\includegraphics[width=22mm]{example-image}}}
         edge from parent[ultra thick, red]% <-- highlight edge from A to final
            }
    child {node{\includegraphics[width=22mm]{example-image-c}}}
    ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly, that's what I'm looking for. Is it possible also to somehow make some of the connecting arrows bold?

Comment: of course it is possible. just add  `edge from parent[very thick,red]` before end of child scope.

Comment: When I add it suddenly the graph structure gets mixed. Where exactly should I add it? For example can you highlight in your picture A->B->Image path?

Comment: See edited answer.